# Helpmate in four and a half moves

Tags: problems

Merry Christmas everyone! Try this problem out that I made yesterday for SuperProblem.ru. With White to move, solve this helpmate, meaning White and Black work together to checkmate Black, in 4.5 moves. Enjoy!

```
[Title "me, SuperProblem.ru 12/24/2020, Helpmate In 4.5"]
[FEN "4b3/6p1/2p2pk1/8/K4r2/P7/2Pq1PPP/8 w - - 0 1"]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
[Variant "From Position"]
[FEN "4b3/6p1/2p2pk1/8/K4r2/P7/2Pq1PPP/8 w - - 0 1"]

1. c4 Rh4 2. g4 Rh7 3. h4 Qh6 4. f4 Bf7
5. f5#
```